# Button Styling in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I have customized the button in this way:

```
<Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Name="DialButton" Click="DialButton_Click" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontSize="43" Name="lblNumber" Margin="0,-5,0,0" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Margin="5,20,0,0" Name="lblCharacter" />
            </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Now, when a user presses the button I want the OnPress state to change the color of the labels. I can do this if it's a simple button by changing the Pressed state. But my label is placed inside a stack panel. How can I change the color in this case? Or in which event can I change the colors of the labels from C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *PropertyChangeAction* in cases like this. You can find this in the *behaviors* category on the *Assets* tab in Expression Blend.

Apply this action on the labels. Change the trigger property to the *DataTrigger* instead of the default EventTrigger. Bind the trigger to the *IsPressed* property of the DialButton. Add two PropertyChangeActions per TextBlock and set the *Value* for one of the to *true* and the other one to *false*.

Here's an example for one of them. The other is exactly the same.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="43" x:Name="lblNumber" Margin="0,-5,0,0" Text="25">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=DialButton}" Value="true">
      <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
        <ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
        </ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
      </ec:ChangePropertyAction>
    </ec:DataTrigger>
    <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=DialButton}" Value="false">
      <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
        <ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}"/>
        </ec:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
      </ec:ChangePropertyAction>
    </ec:DataTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

If the *i:* or *ec:* isn't working, make sure you've got these lines at the top of your xaml file.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Sorskoot. Finally This Is The Solution I Am Looking For. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn this into a custom control and then you can manage the styling of each component based on the state.

Comment: I Am Already Made This UserControl. But Im Unable To Understand How To Do Stying of Each Component Based On State.

Comment: Add an animation to change the properties you want (refering to thte controls by name) when the state changes. You'll see examples of this in the default sytles that are applied to the controls.

Comment: <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
      <Storyboard>                          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
 </VisualState>

In This Where I Can Change My Label Forgroud Color. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the click event of button

```
Button butClicked = (Button)sender;

StackPanel panel1 = (StackPanel)butClicked.Content;
var child1Panel1 = panel1.Children[0] as TextBlock;
child1Panel1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 18, 18, 18));
```

Comment: Hi Alfah,
Actually It Will Not Work As Its One Click Event And It Will Be Performed On Click Event. As I Told You My Requirement is As Button Goes To Pressed State Then My Label Color Changes. And On Release It Goes Normal. Any Way Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to use this button once, probably the easiest way would be to open the .xaml file in Expression Blend, and use Blend to customize the button as you wish, including the state change.  If you're using the button in more than one place, do as Matt suggested and make it a custom control (which you can also use Blend to design) that you can reuse.